# Why does polygon collider 2d restricts movement of player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, physics-engine

I have a cloud which has a polygon collider 2d attached. Also, I have a player that has a box collider 2d attached. When the player lands on the cloud, at some point during the movement, something is stopping him. He is animating but he does not move.

Below is the image of my colliders:

[image: Player & cloud colliders]

When I start running the game, he moves left and right. So I figured it is not a code issue. At a point, he is stuck at the above position and he cannot move right but he can move left. I guess the polygon collider is stopping him from free movement. When I go back, he is walking and when the reaches the above position, he cannot move forward.

Is there any workaround for this?

Below is my code:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 7f;
    public float maxVelocity = 8f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;


    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayerUsingKeyboard();   
    }

    public void MovePlayerUsingKeyboard()
    {
        float forceX = 0f;
        float velocity = Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x);
        Debug.Log("Player Velocity : " + velocity);

        float direction = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (direction < 0)
        {
            if (maxVelocity > velocity)
            {
                anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
                forceX = -speed;                
            }
            //Changing the direction the player faces
            Vector3 temp = transform.localScale;
            temp.x = -1.3f;
            transform.localScale = temp;
        }
        else if (direction > 0)
        {
            if (maxVelocity > velocity)
            {
                anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
                forceX = speed;
            }
            Vector3 temp = transform.localScale;
            temp.x = 1.3f;
            transform.localScale = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        }

        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(forceX, 0));
    }
}
```

[image: Animation nodes]

Comment: Have you tried using a CapsuleCollider2D for your player character rather than a BoxCollider2D?  It looks like the BoxCollider might be getting caught on the PolygonCollider.  KInd of hard to tell from the picture but the polygon collider looks to have a jagged point at the spot where the character is stuck.

Comment: yeah, I tried it. but it bounces a lot making the player jump out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because that the collider of your character is stuck at the bumpy part of the cloud's polygon collider.
A solution is to change the character's collider to semi-capsule collider or capsule collider so that the character can walk smoothly on some rough surfaces.